# Can't return a property of object from a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function test(arr, index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i].index);
    }
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
test(myArr, 'name')
```

But it returns `undefined`. When I use function directly, like this, it works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArr[i].name);
}
```

This is my array:

```
var myArr = [{name: "hamed"}, {name: "hamed1"}]
```

I don't think I should use single quotes when I call a function but without quotes it does not work either.

Comment: When you are doing `arr[i].index`, you are actually looking for property named `index` at `i`th index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to access the property by a variable, use bracket notation. This will evaluate the variable and then find that in the object.

```
function test(arr, index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i][index]);
    }
}
```